# How to display multiple page base64 string to image in HTML

Tags: c#, html, image, base64

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Display Image</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img style='display:block;                 
       src='data:image/jpeg;base64, <!-- base64 data -->' />
  </body>
</html>
```

Here 'base64 data' has multiple pages. But when i try the above code it is just showing only first page. Please help!

Comment: What do you mean? jpeg images do not have pages like .tiff or .ico, and the img tag wouldn't show them anyway.

Comment: Even if i use .tiff, it is still not showing multiple pages

Comment: That is what I am saying, the `<img>` tag doesn't do that.

Comment: How can i display multiple pages then? any suggestions?

Comment: I believe you would have to split the image server-side and create a series of images that you can then put in a carousel or whatever you need.

Comment: can we create an image without storing in server folder only in c# from base64?

Comment: However you generated the dataurl, you will have to save each page of your image to an individual image, then convert it the same way. How you convert it is up to you but I [have a blog post on manipulating images you might find helpful.](https://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/08/manipulating-tiff-images-in-net-without-3rd-party-libraries/)